# CAML query filter for items where the current user is in a "Person or Group" field

Tags: 2010, permissions, filter, people-picker, caml

I have a list with a "Person or Group" field that allows both people or groups.

Is it possible to have a CAML query that gets items where the current user is in that field? It would also have to check if the user is in a group that is in the field.

Say I have a security group called "team" with "user1" in it. And in the list I have an item where the field value is "user2; team". Then if "user2" or "user1" access the list they should see that item but "user3" should not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Membership` query element. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa544234(v=office.14).aspx

> The following example defines a filter for cases where the user is
>   either assigned a task based on membership in a group or assigned a
>   task directly.

```
<Or>
  <Membership Type=\"CurrentUserGroups\">
    <FieldRef Name=\"AssignedTo\"/>
  </Membership>
  <Eq>
    <FieldRef Name=\"AssignedTo\"></FieldRef>
    <Value Type=\"Integer\">
      <UserID/>
    </Value>
  </Eq>
</Or>
```

Comment: Well this is brilliant! Let me give this a whirl.

Comment: Hope it helped :)

Comment: Actually its more of a separate question so let me ask a new one.

Comment: You can in the second part using `Neq`, but I'm not aware of anything for the first part. Not entirely sure what's possible for Membership tag...